# How to sort elasticsearch results based on number of collapsed items?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elastic-stack

I'm using a a query with collapse in order to gather some documents under a certain person, yet I wish to sort the results based on the number of documents in which the search found a match.. this is my query:

```
GET documents/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "text"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "text"
      ],
      "query": "some text"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "person_id",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "top_mathing_docs",
      "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "doc_year",
          "text"
        ]
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you require here is *to sort the documents* i.e. **parent documents**, based on the count of **inner_hits** i.e. count of `inner_hits` based on `person_id`.

So that means, the `_score` of the parent documents in the result doesn't matter.

The only way I've found this doable is making use of the [Top Hits Aggregation for Field Collapse Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_field_collapse_example) and below is what your query would look like.

### Aggregation Query Field Collapse Example:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "text"
      ],
      "query": "some text"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_person_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "person_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_tags_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm assuming `person_id` is of type `keyword` or any `numeric`.
Also if you look at query closely, I've mentioned `"size":"0"`. Which means I'm only returning the result of aggregation.

Another note is that the above aggregation has nothing to do with [Field Collapse in Search Request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html) feature that you have posted in the question. It's just that using this aggregation, your result could be formatted in a similar way.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Kamal I've attempted to use aggregation, but I seem to reach a the same dead-end.. I cannot sort the search results based on the number of of documents that contain the query, grouped by the author. As for collapse, I use it to show some details of the documents, and indeed it's not that relevant, yet in the 'inner_hits' object there in a 'total' variable which is actually what I'm looking for, but I could not find a way to access it and sort the parent objects according to

Comment: @RoyGranit The query I've provided does group based on author and sorts based on documents count. Is it possible for you to share the result as how it is appearing at your end when you execute the above aggregation query?

Comment: That being said, I've tried to achieve what you mentioned i.e. make use of `total` of `inner_hits` and sort them via `sorting based on painless script` but unfortunately that is not possible because of the reasons mentioned in this link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/access-to-inner-hits-from-painless-script-during-sorting/86926/2 If that is what you want, then I'm afraid in that case, you may have to do that kind of computation at your service/client layer. But I would want to wait till you share what output you observe using the aggregation query I've provided and what more you r looking for.

Comment: I've ended up doing an initial query to discover the num of documents and use these numbers to reorder the output of a second query. Thanks for you help.